# How to send an HTML email template from Outlook so that it renders properly in Gmail?

Tags: html, templates, outlook, gmail, rendering

I have an HTML template that renders perfectly in Gmail and Outlook.
However, when I place the template in Outlook, to send to Gmail, the HTML ends up broken (probably because of Outlooks terrible "word" rendering engine)

Is there any way I can save and send an Outlook template that sends plain HTML or a plain HTML file embedded that does not get mangled by Outlook's rendering engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the HTMLBody property of Outlook items and then submit the item for sending.

The Word editor is used by Outlook for displaying emails. You can read more about Word capabilities in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I am pretty familiar with the rendering problems in Outlook so I am looking for a work around - to get Outlook to send HTML to gmail unadulterated. So what is this HTMLBody property you speak of, and what should I change it to?

Answer (score 0):

In a word: **no**

You'll need to create a html template from scratch* (see below) which will render correctly in outlook, gmail and all the other wonderful mail clients. I'm afraid it is a minefield, every client renders differently and it can become a struggle to implement all the quirks of each client.

*however there is help! [litmus responsive email templates](https://litmus.com/blog/go-responsive-with-these-7-free-email-templates-from-stamplia) are amazing at giving you a head start - and they work perfectly on phones and tablets as well!

If you don't feel up to HTML code, and prefer a more WYSIWYG approach - I'd recommend getting a free [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) account, you can even copy the code out when you've finished designing (but I'd just send from mailchimp really)!

Hope that helps